# Google Earth Plugin had an internal error in jquery-ui dialog (1.10.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am popping up the google earth plugin within a jquery-ui dialog.  This was working with jquery-ui 1.9.2 but after upgrading to 1.10.2 the plugin loads but when trying to move the dialog, google earth stops working with a "The Google Earth Plugin had an internal error.  Try reloading the page."

This happens on both Win7 and OSX 10.8.2 and it happens in both Chrome & Safari.
Anyone else experiencing this issue?  Workarounds?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/murdog/sysPX/10/) for the code below, if you downgrade jquery-ui to 1.9.2 all works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>

var loaded = false;

function loadGE() {
    google.load('earth', '1', {
        callback: function () {
            google.earth.createInstance('editmap3d', function (instance) {
                initEditGE(instance);
            }, function () {
                failureGE();
            });
        }
    });
}

function initEditGE(instance) {
    loaded = true;
    ge = instance;

    var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
    lookAt.setLatitude(36.584207);
    lookAt.setLongitude(-121.754322);
    lookAt.setRange(5000.0); //default is 0.0

    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);
}

function failureGE() {
    console.log("GE failed to load...");
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#opendialog").button().click(function () {
        $("#editDialog").dialog("open");

        if (!loaded) loadGE();
    });

    $("#editDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
})


</script>

<body>
    <div>GE in popup</div>
    <button id="opendialog">open</button>
    <div id="editDialog">
        <div id="mapcontainer" style="width:600; height:600;">
            <div id="editmap3d" style="height:100%;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears it has something to do with MouseEvents.  On OSX as soon as you try to click on the map it throws the error, but you can still interact via the API (add/remove layers, pan/zoom, etc) without issue.  On windows you can interact with the map, but as soon as you try to move the dialog the error occurs.

Comment: I am doing something similar and ran into the same issues. However, it works with jQuery-ui 1.10.1 and Firefox 20 without issues. I haven't tried other configurations/combinations. Curious...

Answer (score 0):

I've actually observed something similar with 1.10.1 where the plugin loads and then crashes. What I did notice was it works fine with the non-minified version but crashes with the minified version of 1.10.1.

Edit: My problem with not with jquery-ui though but with jquery and google earth. Using UI 1.10.3 and it seems to work ok with either min and not min.